# How to setup Google Analytics Form Submission Goals in SiteCore

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My website is built on Sitecore CMS.

We have a /contact-us/ page where a form is provided for users. Once the click on Submit button, the same page loads with a submission confirmation message.

I want to setup goals on how many times successful submissions are done.

So how to configure conversion goals?

I think I can use "event" from Google Tag Manager.. but not sure how to find a page-id or form-id in SiteCore.

Answer (score 2):

A disclaimer: I have never used Sitecore CMS, however, my suggestions are generic and should work, regardless of CMS platform.

Answer - I can think of 2 approaches to the problem:

1. Google Analytics Goals: You can set a new custom goal. This goal will be a destination goal that fires when the /contact-us/ page is reached. In addition, you will add a funnel step with Required turned on and set it to the same /contact-us/ page. This method has a downside though, the actual number of conversions will be visible only in the Funnel Visualization report while all other reports for the asset will show the number of times the first /contact-us/ page was visited (which might be larger than the actual number of conversions).
2. Google Tag Manager Event: That's what I would do to achieve your goal. If you are unsure about how to create the actual Event, then ask and I will edit my answer. In order to find the form-id you need to go through your page source (in most browsers it's right-click "View Page Source" or something along those lines), and actually search for it by hand. There might be a more efficient way with your CMS, but as I said, I never worked with it.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi thanks, I am still checking with if there is any useful method. Right now I can only setup "conversion goal" on a page visit...